# Unable to upload Azure Storage File Share File from browser using Rest API (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, azure, http, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am attempting to upload a file from a browser directly to a File Share File. The [operation's spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file) is pretty straight forward, send an HTTP PUT request to a URL (with a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature)) along with some headers. I attempted to implement this with a simple HTML form and some backing JavaScript in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acwyxzoj). To my surprise the system fails, and responds XML indicating that the `Content-Length` header is incorrect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
  <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Time:0000-00-00T00:00:00.0000000Z</Message>
  <HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
  <HeaderValue>12345</HeaderValue>
</Error>
```

I double checked the documentation, and it indicates that the `Content-Length` header should not be present, or it should have a value specifically containing `0`. I did some digging, and [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) is a [forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), which means you can't adjust the value programmatically.

To my puzzle, using the embeddd Azure Storage Explorer within [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) jumps through some kind of hoops in order to specify `Content-Length:0`.

My goals are to:

- Use the REST API from the browser
- Not introduce any external libraries
- Not introduce any servers

Is there way to use the REST API from the browser?

Some things that I have already checked:

- I have tried forcing `Content-Length:0` via the `headers` property.
- I have ensured that CORS settings in my Azure Storage Account (for Files) have been updated to account for my browser's location.
- I have attempted to integrate with [Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) as a comparison, which works great in the sample, but not what I am interested in for my project.
- I have tried working with the API out of the browser, and I have no issues sending in the same request (of course `Content-Length:0` deviates as requested by the specification).
- I have tried mimicking the request headers as much as possible from a recorded XHR that was made from the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a file in File Storage is different than uploading a blob.

In File Storage, first thing you would need to do is create an empty file using [`Create File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file) REST operation. During this operation you specify the size of file you wish to create (your content's length) in `x-ms-content-length` request header.

Once an empty file is created, you send the content to write to the file using [`Put Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range) operation. This is where you actually send the content. You would need to use either `Range` or `x-ms-range` request header to specify where exactly in that empty file you wish to write the data you're sending.

Based on these, I modified your code. Here're the modified methods:

```
async function upload(url, headers, content) {           
    if (!url) { return; }

    const init = {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: content,
        headers: headers
    };
    console.log(init);
    const response = await fetch(url, init);

    document.getElementById('response-content').innerText = await response.text();
}

async function uploadToFileStorage() {
    console.log('creating empty file');
    const url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    const content = document.getElementById('content').value;
    const headers = {
      'content-length': 0,
      'x-ms-type': 'file',
      'x-ms-content-length': content.length
    }
    await upload(url, headers, '');
    console.log('empty file created.');
    const url2 = url + '&comp=range';
    const headers2 = {
        'Content-Length': content.length,
        'x-ms-version': '2015-02-21',
        'Range': 'bytes=0-' + (content.length-1),
        'x-ms-write': 'update'
    };
    await upload(url2, headers2, content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! After seeing this, I can see how I overlooked the Azure Portal implementation by missing the fact the first request had no content.